# I am trying to integrate paypal ipn to my website. I keep receiving the following error. Im at my wits end here. What am I missing?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to integrate paypal ipn to my website. I keep receiving the following error. Im at my wits end here. What am I missing??? I guess Im am just not understanding why the ipn.php page would not be seeing what paypal is sending to the POST variable or is this even the issue? I have been at it all day and I am new to this process so any help would be great!!

```
INVALID
[2015-12-02 17:39 America/Denver] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate
```

Here is my code
ipn.php

```
<?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

orderdetails.php

```
<?php
require 'ipn.php';

?>

<form target="_new" method="post" action="https://www.kathyhaggerty.info/Final/ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="SomePayPalVar" value="SomeValue1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="SomeOtherPPVar" value="SomeValue2"/>

<!-- code for other variables to be tested ... -->

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<br />
Thank you for your payment. Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you. You may log into your account at <a href="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ie">www.sandbox.paypal.com/ie</a> to view details of this transaction.
```

index.php

```
<!-- INFO: The post URL "checkout.php" is invoked when clicked on "Pay with PayPal" button.-->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action='checkout.php' METHOD='POST'>
    <input type='image' name='paypal_submit' id='paypal_submit'  src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_dg_pay_w_paypal.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Pay with PayPal'/>
</form>
</body>

<!-- Add Digital goods in-context experience. Ensure that this script is added before the closing of html body tag -->

<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>


<script>

    var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(
    {
        trigger: 'paypal_submit',
        expType: 'instant'
         //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
    });

</script>

</html>
```

I am at a loss!!

Comment: I did use the int wizard so i really may just be doing this all wrong!! uggg!!

Answer (score 0):

That is an incorrect way of implementing IPN.

First of all, since you are using ExpressCheckout, have you done `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API call? This is because I don't see it in your question.

I am assuming that the orderdetails.php is your Return URL you have set since there is a Thank you message underneath. However, I did not see any `DoExpressCheckoutPayments` being called.

Without DoEC API call, the transaction is not complete and your IPN will always be Invalid.

If you are following through the Integration Wizard, you should be able to reach Step 4: Make Payment whereby it gives you the whole code as [orderconfirm.php](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecdigitalgoods/confirm.php), that is the full code of how you should implement DoEC API call.

### It's a must to complete and ensure the above, then here is what you need to do to get IPN working:

Regarding the IPN, you can set the URL in the DoEC API call.

In the orderconfirm.php, find the chunk of code and insert $ipnUrl as below:

```
    //Format the  parameters that were stored or received from GetExperessCheckout call.
    $token              = $_REQUEST['token'];
    $payerID            = $_REQUEST['PayerID'];
    $paymentType        = 'Sale';
    $currencyCodeType   = $res['CURRENCYCODE'];
    $ipnUrl             = 'https://www.kathyhaggerty.info/Final/ipn.php'; 
    $items = array();
    $i = 0;
    // adding item details those set in setExpressCheckout
    while(isset($res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$i"]))
    {
        $items[] = array('name' => $res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$i"], 'amt' => $res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT$i"], 'qty' => $res["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY$i"]);
        $i++;
    }

    $resArray = ConfirmPayment ( $token, $paymentType, $currencyCodeType, $payerID, $finalPaymentAmount, $items, $ipnUrl );
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
```

After that, go to your [paypalfunctions.php](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecdigitalgoods/download.php?file=pplibfile), find the function `ConfirmPayment`, and edit the code below (or you can just replace the whole `ConfirmPayment` function with mine):

```
function ConfirmPayment( $token, $paymentType, $currencyCodeType, $payerID, $FinalPaymentAmt, $items, $ipnUrl )
    {
        /* Gather the information to make the final call to
           finalize the PayPal payment.  The variable nvpstr
           holds the name value pairs
           */
        $token              = urlencode($token);
        $paymentType        = urlencode($paymentType);
        $currencyCodeType   = urlencode($currencyCodeType);
        $payerID            = urlencode($payerID);
        $serverName         = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
        $ipnUrl         = urlencode($ipnUrl);

    $nvpstr  = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL=' . $ipnUrl;
        $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName; 

        foreach($items as $index => $item) {

            $nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME" . $index . "=" . urlencode($item["name"]);
            $nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" . $index . "=" . urlencode($item["amt"]);
            $nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY" . $index . "=" . urlencode($item["qty"]);
            $nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY" . $index . "=Digital";
        }
         /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
            If an error occured, show the resulting errors
            */
        $resArray=hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",$nvpstr);

        /* Display the API response back to the browser.
           If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
           If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
           */
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

        return $resArray;
    }
```

Once you have done, put every file together and if everything works fine, IPN should be triggered automatically upon completed payment (after `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` API have been called in orderconfirm.php)